# Size of an hashed array with pseudorandom hashing method

Tags: c, data-structures, hash

I'm confused of setting a good and efficient size of an hashed array. The book that i'm reading says that the load factor should be around 75% to be a good hashed array. But I have no idea how to theoretically decide the size of the array before I actually try testing the hashed array putting keys. Are there any clue or crucial tips in reaching the best hashed array size? and does the size dependent on the method you use for hashing?

Comment: The size is not constant... I hope you get that.

Comment: I think the size depends on the load factor rather than the method you use for hashing. As for the initial size of the array, if you don't know the number of input, then just make a small size array and extend it (double it up and rehash everything) as you insert into the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

Your hash table solution should *not* depend on knowing beforehand the number of elements to be put in the table.  Instead, a dynamically growing and shrinking one is best.

Recommend initializing with a small hash table size ( <= 1) and about quadrupling the hash table size as the load factor hit 150-200%.  This involves re-hashing the entire old table into a new one, but should not happen too often in real-life examples.

There should also be shrink thresholds that are about 1/2 the growth ones.

By having the growth and shrink thresholds far from each other, you prevent a lot of work should you be adding/deleting hash table elements around a critical size.

Hash table sizes have an additional benefit is they are a prime number.  The typical hash function consists of some pre-hash function, say `unsigned Hash(unsigned item)` then modding the result with the hash table size: `BucketIndex = Hash(item)%HashTableSize`  A prime hash table size gives improved dispersal should the `Hash()` not do so well.

For prime values, I recommend keeping a HashPrime_Index in your Hash data structure, then use the following table when you need to know the hash table's size.

```
static const size_t HashPrime[] = { 0, 2, 3, 7, 13, 31, 61, ... }; // Primes just less than powers of 2.
```

When growing, use 0, 3, 13, ...  When shrinking use ..., 61, 13, 2.

The optimal hash table size much less depends on the method `Hash()` when you use prime hash table sizes.  Note: Hash() should return a large integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can *rehash* your hash table as the number of elements grows. This process changes the number of buckets. Depending on the details, this may even be *necessary*.

- If you use chaining (i.e. all elements with the same hash value go into the same bucket), then you can theoretically grow the table indefinitely without rehashing, but it eventually becomes essentially just a linked list (or whatever sequence container represents a bucket). So you should keep track of the current load factor (number of elements divided by number of buckets) and grow the table when that gets too big.
- If you use probing ("open addressing"), you *have* to rehash once the probing fails to find a free spot for a new element anyway.

Comment: @nhahtdh: How so? What do you do when the probing fails?